# How can I filter a dataframe by a column that indicates the app version?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, version, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe like:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, '3.1.5'],
                            [2, '1.23.0'],
                            [3, '0.2.0'],
                            [4, None]], ['Row', 'Version'])
```

And I want to filter it for the upper versions of a determinate version. E.g v = '1.2.0'

Expected:

```
+---+-------+
|Row|Version|
+---+-------+
|  1|  3.1.5|
|  2| 1.23.0|
+---+-------+
```

I tried use the library packaging in a UDF

```py
from packaging import version
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def version_parse(text):
    try:
        vers = version.parse(text)
    except TypeError:
        vers = None        
    return str(vers)
version_parse_udf = F.udf(version_parse, T.StringType())

df = df.filter(version_parse_udf(F.col('Version')) > version.parse('1.2.0'))
```

But it gives me the exception

> AttributeError: 'Version' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: you should write a udf function to compare the version objects and return true or false. Then use this udf to filter the based on true and false returned from udf.

Comment: You can simply filter  with df.filter(F.col("Version")>"1.2.0")

Comment: @AnnaK. - take a look at my answer, The approach you suggested in the comment would not work in all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @yadavlpsir

```
def version_parse(vers: str, boundary_vers: str) -> bool:
    try:
        vers = version.parse(vers) >= version.parse(boundary_vers)
    except TypeError:
        vers = False        
    return vers
version_parse_udf = F.udf(version_parse, T.BooleanType())

df = df.filter(version_parse_udf(F.col('Version'), F.lit('1.2.0')))
```

It works to me

Comment: UDF is slow. Go for native Spark. You can solve the vast majority of problems without using udf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Having this as the input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[1, '3.1.5'],
     [2, '1.23.0'],
     [3, '0.2.0'],
     [4, None],
     [5, '1.3.0']],
    ['Row', 'Version'])
```

The simple following filter would not work:

```py
df.filter(F.col("Version") > "1.20.0").show()
# +---+-------+
# |Row|Version|
# +---+-------+
# |  1|  3.1.5|
# |  2| 1.23.0|
# |  5|  1.3.0|
# +---+-------+
```

You could make use of `split` which divides the version `major.minor.patch` into array of integers `[major, minor, patch]`. Then the comparison would work.

```py
def vers(v): return F.transform(F.split(v, "\."), lambda x: x.cast('int'))
df = df.filter(vers("Version") > vers(F.lit("1.20.0")))

df.show()
# +---+-------+
# |Row|Version|
# +---+-------+
# |  1|  3.1.5|
# |  2| 1.23.0|
# +---+-------+
```

For Spark 2.4+

```py
def vers(v): return F.expr(fr"transform(split({v}, '\\.'), x -> cast(x as int))")
df = df.filter(vers("Version") >= vers("'1.20.0'"))
```

Comment: i'm guessing this is only available starting spark 3.1+?

Comment: True, because of `F.transform`

Comment: to whoever it may concern, if the `transform()` isn't available in your spark version, you can use the higher order function with `expr()`. -- `func.expr('transform(split(version, "[\.]"), x -> int(x))')`